# Classpath issue in leinigen

Tags: clojure, classpath, leiningen

I've been striving to build a standalone .jar with leiningen. Though having gone through the examples on [github](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) and [Alex Ott's Website](http://alexott.net/en/clojure/ClojureLein.html) and some related questions, I couldn't figure out how to correctly set up the project. After doing `lein uberjar` in the project it complains

```
Could not locate clojure/contrib/string__init.class or clojure/contrib/string.clj on classpath:  (collision.clj:1)
```

My project directory looks like

```
.
├── classes
├── lib
│   ├── clojure-1.2.1.jar
│   └── clojure-contrib-1.1.0.jar
├── project.clj
└── src
   └── collision
        └── collision.clj
```

My `project.clj`:

```
(defproject collision "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.1.0"]]
  :main collision.collision)
```

`collision.clj`:

```
(ns collision.collision
  (:require 
    clojure.set
    clojure.string
    [clojure.contrib.string :as st]
    [clojure.contrib.str-utils :as su]
    [clojure.contrib.combinatorics :as cmbn]))

... defns ...

(defn -main []
  (...))

(-main)
```

The code works on the REPL. How do I tell leiningen where to to find `clojure-contrib-1.1.0.jar`? I'm not a Java programmer and not really accustomed to the classpath issue; quick and dirty help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you run lein deps? Can you find the jar file under the appropriate .m2 directory like this from my lein script CLOJURE_JAR="$HOME/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.2.1/clojure-1.2.1.jar"

Answer (score 1):

try using `[org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]` instead `[org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.1.0"]`

in the version 1.1.0 not exist the namespace `clojure.contrib.string`